# What's wrong in detection of location?

Tags: java, android, location, locationlistener

I need to get location of android device. But have some problem with it : `getLastKnownLocation()` returns null value. Perhaps problem in custom `LocationListener`, but i don't know how to fix it. Can somebody help me?

Here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

private Pair <String, String>  getLocation()
{
    Pair< String, String > result = Pair.create("null", "null");
    GeoLocatorListener geoLocatorListener = new GeoLocatorListener();
    Location currentLocation;
    Boolean isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if ( !isGpsEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled )
        return result;

    long minWaitTime = 1000 * 10;       // 10 minutes
    float minDistance = 100;            // 100 metres

    if ( isGpsEnabled )
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minWaitTime, minDistance, geoLocatorListener);
        currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    else
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, minWaitTime, minDistance, geoLocatorListener);
        currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    if ( currentLocation != null )
        return Pair.create(String.valueOf(currentLocation.getAltitude()),String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLongitude()));
    return result;
}
```

custom `LocationListener` class - `GeoLocatorListener`

```
public class GeoLocatorListener implements LocationListener {
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically when you ask for the **lastKnownLocation()**, you can get back a location or null. Another thing that you have to check is that your location is updated because it can be out of time.

I guess/suppose that you are developing an application that will run on devices with the Google Play installed (+GooglePlay services) and because of that I suggest you to have a look at [fused location](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html).

In this way you can delegate and take advantage of the GooglePlay Services to retrieve your location getting rid of all the algorithms and problems those raise when you're doing a location based app.

Comment: Why I can't use that methods?

Comment: I'm not saying that you don't have to use them but be aware that you'll have to work a bit more without taking advantage of the Play Services. Most of the time the Play Services algorithms satisfy what you need when you're querying for a location as soon as you start your application. If you need to implement everything from the scratch you have to:
getLastKnownLocation > check if it's the one that satisfy your constraints > if not asking to one/more enabled providers the location and manage failures,...